# How to find connected road elements in a tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have a list of lines and points and I need to get the list of connected lines based on points.

The input is Line and its 2 points so in the above example input is

[image]

In Tabular format

[image]

And the output should be 2 lists
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and [8]

I was creating a map of point to list of lines it belongs

A - 1

B - 1,2,3

C - 2
...

and then trying to merge the list of lines where common points are found. But not able to find the correct way to merge those lines.
Can there be simple or another solution to it?

Comment: Yours is the problem of identifying the connected components of an undirected graph.  You should be able to find plenty of information about that with those search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Are 3 and 5 different lines?
If yes, then it is obvious that each line can have no more than 2 points.
If no, then a tabular format is not appropriate.

If I were you, I would do one Map with a line as the key and a List of points as the value.
Then create an interface to define if a point belongs to several lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an adjacent map of points to point-lines.

You define what are the adjacent points of a given point and what are the lines:

```
class PointAdj {
    String point;
    String line;//Or int
}
```

Define the map as:

```
Map<String, List<PointAdj>> pontAdjMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Start reading from the table and fill the map:

(I assume the input is a two dimensional array called input)

```
for (int i =0; i < input.length; i++) {

    String[] row = input[i];
    List<PointAdj>> adj = pontAdjMap.putIfAbsent(row[1], new ArrayList<>());
    if(adj == null) {
        adj = pontAdjMap.get(row[1]);
    }
    adj.add(new PointAdj(row[2], row[0]));
    //Also put the reverse side
}
```

Now pontAdjMap contains all points with their adjacent points.

Now define a list of Set to add lines and loop the map and add lines as much as possible.

Use a queue to continuously traverse adjacent points;

```
List<Set<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
final Set<String> calculated = new HashSet();//Takes care of redundant processing of points;
pontAdjMap.keySet().foreach(pointInMap->{
    Set<String> lineSet = new HashSet();
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    queue.offer(pointInMap);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        String point = queue.poll();
        if(calculated.add(point)) {
            for(PointAdj pa: pontAdjMap.get(point)) {
                lineSet.add(pa.line);
                queue.offer(pa.point);
            }
        }
    }
    if(lineSet.size() > 0) {
        lines.add(lineSet);
    }
});
```

Now lines should be the final result.

**Please note that I did't test this solution and it may contain some edge case issues. But I think the overall idea is ok.**